# Failed to convert from bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode

After updating to iOS 17 and Xcode 15, the following warning appears in Xcode:

> -warning-
> nw_parameters_set_source_application_by_bundle_id_internal Failed to convert from bundle ID (my bundel ID) to UUID. This could lead to wrong data usage accounting.

How do I solve this problem?

It worked great before and I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like we can ignore that.

Apples answer in Apples forum:  ["I’d classify that as log noise."](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/739086?answerId=767505022#767505022)

Comment: I received the same response from Apple. Thank you! 

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115461